# Apply theme in SharePoint Online using REST api or PNP JS

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions

I am looking for a solution to apply existing theme in SharePoint Modern Site using code.

Answer (score 1):

The [Official Documentation on Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-rest-api) gives us a few REST calls to manage your tenant themes:

```
http://<site url>/_api/thememanager/AddTenantTheme
http://<site url>/_api/thememanager/RemoveTenantTheme
http://<site url>/_api/thememanager/GetTenantThemingOptions
```

Since add/removing themes is a tenant scoped feature, you must have the clearance to manage them (Tenant Admin).

If you wish to apply a classic theme to a modern site, [here is a link](http://blog.pixelmill.com/3348/changing-colors-modern-site/) that gives a script to use.

To select the correct theme in a site, this is a manual procedure (I haven't found an endpoint, but there may be) which is pretty simple (Cog in the ribbon > Change the look > Select your theme).

Rolling out pretty soon (announced without a release date I believe), Hub sites will automatically apply the hub theme to any site you decide to attach.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are other methods in that `thememanager` toolkit that are not mentioned in the prior response.  Specifically, I am referring to `ApplyTheme`

Here is some sample code from the MS Docs / Learning site.

```
function RestRequest(url,params) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.onreadystatechange = function ()
  {
    if (req.readyState != 4) // Loaded
      return;
    console.log(req.responseText);
  };
  // Prepend web URL to url and remove duplicated slashes.
  var webBasedUrl = (_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "//" + url).replace(/\/{2,}/,"/");
  req.open("POST",webBasedUrl,true);
  req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
  req.setRequestHeader("ACCEPT", "application/json; odata.metadata=minimal");
  req.setRequestHeader("x-requestdigest", _spPageContextInfo.formDigestValue);
  req.setRequestHeader("ODATA-VERSION","4.0");
  req.send(params ? JSON.stringify(params) : void 0);
}

var pal = {
    "palette" : {
        "themePrimary": "#1BF242",
        "themeLighterAlt": "#0d0b00",
        "themeLighter": "#0b35bc",
        "themeLight": "#322d00",
        "themeTertiary": "#6a5f00",
       "themeSecondary": "#1B22F2",
        "themeDarkAlt": "#ffe817",
        "themeDark": "#ffed4b",
        "themeDarker": "#fff171",
        "neutralLighterAlt": "#252525",
        "neutralLighter": "#282828",
        "neutralLight": "#313131",
        "neutralQuaternaryAlt": "#3f3f3f",
        "neutralQuaternary": "#484848",
        "neutralTertiaryAlt": "#4f4f4f",
        "neutralTertiary": "#c8c8c8",
        "neutralSecondaryAlt": "#d0d0d0",
        "neutralSecondary": "#dadada",
        "neutralPrimary": "#ffffff",
        "neutralDark": "#eaeaea",
        "black": "#f8f8f8",
        "white": "#1f1f1f",
        "primaryBackground": "#1f1f1f",
        "primaryText": "#ffffff",
        "error": "#ff5f5f"
    }
}
RestRequest("/_api/thememanager/ApplyTheme", {name:"Sounders Rave Green", themeJson: JSON.stringify(pal)});
```

Full Article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-rest-api